# FooTable Custom Toggle Button

Tags: jquery, html, css, footable

The little toggle button for FooTable comes from the following css

```
.footable.breakpoint > tbody > tr.footable-detail-show > td > span.footable-toggle:before {
    content: "\e000";
}

.footable.breakpoint > tbody > tr > td > span.footable-toggle:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
```

However, I would like to replace it with a triangle which uses the following CSS and HTML

```
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 9px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  right: -6px !important;
}


 <div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

I am not sure if this possible, or how to go about so any advice would be great!

(Link for FooTable Toggle Icons http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/icon-styles.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the style of `arrow-down` to the specified selector. Try

```
.footable.breakpoint > tbody > tr.footable-detail-show > td > span.footable-toggle:before {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 9px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  right: -6px !important;
}

.footable.breakpoint > tbody > tr > td > span.footable-toggle:before {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 9px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  right: -6px !important;
}
```

Comment: Had to make a few small adjustments but worked! Cheers